# Siebel Input fields fluctuate

Tags: input, scroll, field, siebel

I facing issue regarding fluctuation of Input fields in Siebel

Input fields fluctuate on scrolling.

I’ve done following troubleshooting.

Added in trusted site.
Added in compatibility view settings.
Tried in private browsing.
Graphics Driver installation.
EMIESiteListManager.msi
Windows 10 (IE 11) re-installed

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with 'fluctuate'?

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Siebel is openui, most probably this is javascript issue. Open the browser console and see if there are javascript issues there, try to add the missing files to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to different versions of browser objects, try clearing your browser cache & restart browser.